# Why do Scala maps print an extra value when iterating with foreach?

Tags: scala, dictionary

When iterating through a map like so:

```
val powers = Map("Spark man" -> "Electricity", "Bubble man" -> "Fires Bubbles", "Guts man" -> "No idea")
println(powers.size)
println(powers.foreach(man => println(man._1 + " -> " + man._2)))
```

Why does it seem to produce a fourth item when printing as such:

```
3
Spark man -> Electricity
Bubble man -> Fires Bubbles
Guts man -> No idea
()
```

With the braces on the last line being the part confusing me.

As you can probably tell I'm quite new to the language, so it's likely something simple, but I can't seem to find anything relating to this.

Comment: Plus one for Bubble man, but I'm still curious about Guts man.  Is it that Guts man actually guts a man of his *brain* so that he is left with *No idea*?  "Bob, what do you think of this?"  "I have -- no idea."  "OMG, they cut out his *brain*!"  BTW, try examples out on the REPL (aka `scala`) and it will Print for you (the P in REPL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`powers.foreach(man => println(man._1 + " -> " + man._2)` returns the value of type `Unit` - this value is displayed as `()`.

You are printing this value as well as each pair in the map, so your code is effectively the same as

```
val u: Unit = powers.foreach(man => println(man._1 + " -> " + man._2)
println(u)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have in the last line **2 println**'s

```
println(powers.foreach(man => println(man._1 + " -> " + man._2)))
```

The inner `println` is printing the 3 man lines and the outer one is printing the `()`

Comment: Well spotted! I guess I couldn't see the wood for the trees on this one. Lee's explanation is a little better so I'm going to accept his answer, but I will vote you up for being so prompt.